# NSOutlineView detect when children are collapsed

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to store the actual collapsed/expanded state of items in a `NSOutlineView`, such that it can be restored later. There are two methods available on `NSOutlineViewDelegate`:

- `outlineViewItemDidExpand(Notification)`
- `outlineViewItemDidCollapse(Notification)`

The problem is that these methods are not only called for the item the user clicks on, but for collapsible children as well. Example:

```
- a
-- b
--- c
```

When `a` is collapsed `outlineViewItemDidCollapse` is called twice, once for `b` and once for `a`. Marking both as **collapsed** is incorrect, since `b` should still be expanded and `c` should be visible after expanding `a` again. So the actual state for `b` should be **expanded**.

When a user Option-clicks on `a` all children are collapsed as well (`outlineView.collapseItem(item, collapseChildren: true)`). After expanding `a` again, `b` should stay collapsed. The state for `b` should be **collapsed** in this case.

The two different states:

- `a`: **collapsed**, `b`: **expanded** (but hidden due to parent)
- `a`: **collapsed**, `b`: **collapsed** (and hidden due to parent)

Is there any way to differentiate between these two actions/states, such that I can properly restore it later?

Comment: "When a user Option-clicks on a all children are collapsed as well "  Que!?  Why do you need to hold down the option key?

Comment: @ElTomato That's default macOS behaviour: ["this method is invoked with the collapseChildren parameter set to true when a user Option-clicks the disclosure triangle for an item in the outline view"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview/1531436-collapseitem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:

`NSOutlineView` can save and restore the expanded items (`autosaveExpandedItems`). The settings can be retrieved from `NSUserDefaults`. The key is `NSOutlineView Items <autosaveName>`.

Subclass `NSOutlineView` and override `expandItem(_:expandChildren:)` and `collapseItem(_:collapseChildren:)`. The methods are not called for the children.

It might be possible to figure out which item is expanded or collapsed using the current event in `outlineViewItemWillExpand(_:)` and `outlineViewItemWillCollapse(_:)`.

Comment: Subclassing `NSOutlineView` looks like the way to go, thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to give a revised answer...*

Apparently there is no easy way to recover whether a given container is expanded or collapsed once its parent object has been collapsed. Clearly something in the inner workings of the outline view remembers — possibly it's something as simple as storing the state of the cell view's disclosure button cell, or possibly it sets up a flag in the tree controller or its nodes — but in any case there's no direct programmatic interface. I suspect you'll have to keep track of it in the model object.

To do that, add a boolean property to your model item, such as:

```
@property BOOL currentlyExpanded;
```

Then you'll want to implement the two delegate methods `outlineViewItemDidExpand:` and `outlineViewItemWillCollapse:`, like so (this is assuming you are using a tree controller for the outline view):

```
- (void)outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTreeNode * node = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSObject"];
    NSOutlineView * ov = notification.object;
    MyModelItem * item = [node representedObject];

    /*
      because we can only expand a visible container, we merely note
      that this container is now expanded in our view. This will be 
      called for every container that is expanded, so we don't have to 
      think about it much.
    */
    item.currentlyExpanded = YES;
}

- (void)outlineViewItemWillCollapse:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSTreeNode * node = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"NSObject"];
    NSOutlineView * ov = notification.object;
    MyModelItem * item = [node representedObject];

    /* 
      Elements are collapsed from top to bottom. A collapsed parent 
      means the collapse started someplace farther up the chain than 
      our current item, so the expansion state of the current item is 
      not going to change unless the option key is held down, or you 
      implement a collapseItem:collapseChildren: with the second 
      parameter as YES. This accounts for the first; you'll have to 
      deal with the second in code.
    */

    BOOL optionKeyIsDown = [[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] && NSEventModifierFlagOption;

    if ([ov isItemExpanded:[node parentNode]] || optionKeyIsDown) {
        item.currentlyExpanded = NO;
    }   
}
```

These should keep the model item property `currentlyExpanded` synced with the outline view's internal expansion table (whatever that is). If you want to refer to it or store it in a database you can access it straight from the model objects.

The way I handled the bitmask throws a warning, but I'm too lazy to fix it...

*Preserving this last part after the edit, because I think it's good info...*

Normally you do not have to worry about any of this; NSOutlineView will 'do the right thing' of its own accord. If the user clicks the disclosure triangle of a container and then reopens it, all of the subcontainers will retain their expanded/collapsed states; if a user option-clicks the control triangle, all of the subcontainers will be marked as expanded or collapsed (depending on whether the user is option-opening or option-closing the parent). Don't bother with it unless you want some specialized behavior (which you would generally set up in the delegate methods `outlineView:shouldCollapseItem:` and `outlineView:shouldExpandItem:`).

If you're trying to retain the expansion state across app invocations, set the NSOutlineView property `autosaveExpandedItems` to true. No bookkeeping necessary...

Comment: `isItemExpanded` is unfortunately `false` for all nested children when their parent is collapsed, even if the child is actually expanded behind the scenes. `shouldCollapseItem`/`shouldExpandItem` are also called for all children when their parent is collapsed/expanded. `autosaveExpandedItems` would indeed be the solution normally, except if you want to manage where it is stored (e.g. database) or need extra bookkeeping logic. Is there any way to extract the state that `autosaveExpandedItems` stores?

Comment: That bit about `isItemExpanded:` surprises me; it's unintuitive. That's what I get for assuming things will work the way I think the will work. Let me play with it a bit and see if what I come up with

Comment: Apple thinks `hidden == collapsed` for some reason. Here's a quick gist you can play around with: [gist](https://gist.github.com/floorish/4e13c7c28e211274b8d5a2dd32dcdc1a) Just create a new project and connect the view/window outlets from IB

Comment: @floorish - Ok, I played with it a bit, and I see what you'll likely have to do. I'll rewrite my answer to explain. I'm not quite sure how to use the 'hidden ==  collapsed' thing you've noted. While I figure it's true, and NSTableView has a method for retrieving hidden rows, I don't see how it helps. But I'll think about it a bit before I edit.

Comment: @floorish - revised answer,

Comment: Thanks! Using `currentEvent` does indeed work but looks a bit fragile. (It doesn't capture manually calling `collapseItem(item, collapseChildren: true)` but that's trivial to track). By 'hidden' I meant 'inherited collapsed state', sorry for the confusion. I think subclassing `NSOutlineView` might be the way to go though, seems more robust. Cheers

Comment: @floorish - ok, but be advised that the docs recommend against trying to subclass NSOutlineView.

Comment: Yes I am aware (I was already guilty of doing that in this particular project so I don't care that much) But good point to keep in mind :)